# How can I write a regular expression to match lines not ending with a phrase?

Tags: php, regex

I need a PHP regular expression that matches a line beginning, but not ending, with a phrase. Something like:

```
$s = 'top bus stop';
$b = preg_match('/^top.*(?!top)$/', $s);
```

But one that actually works. What do you think?

Comment: Can you give more example of what is and what is not valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had it almost right. But the final assertion should be `(?<!top)` a lookbehind assertion using a  `<` prefix. This way it really looks at the preceding three characters before the `$` subject end.